# mysql command is not found after installing using homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I uninstalled newest mysql and tried to install mysql 5.7 on Mac by downloading from offical website, however it said the previous version is still installed on my Mac. I tried all methods I found, and they didn't work. I also couldn't found any mysql files on my Mac. So I installed mysql using home brew. And the path is {/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29}. I followed some method and opened bash_profile[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brqBd.png)

I changed path to {/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/bin}, and I still got a command not found. I once also get mysql running by using {brew services start mysql@5.7}, but when I type {mysql -u root -p} it showed: " /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: No such file or directory".

Really appreciate it if anyone know what's the problem here.

Answer (score 16):

i had this problem too. looks like the installer isn't creating the symlink for some reason. this should fix it.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s ../Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/bin/mysql mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

As Homebrew says

> mysql@5.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
> because this is an alternate version of another formula.

> If you need to have mysql@5.7 first in your PATH, run:

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Reload zsh config after installed.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Or open a new terminal.