# mac intel chip 'zsh: command not found: mysql' after install through brew

Tags: mysql, homebrew

It is complicate situation

1. I installed mysql@5.7 through brew
2. zsh can't find mysql command. so, I add mysql path to ~/.zprofile
3. but still zsh can't find mysql, in addition can't find brew
4. if I remove mysql path, then zsh can find brew but not myqsl

---

this is my ~/.zprofile

```bash
# Added by Toolbox App
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"

export MVN=${HOME}/Library/apache-maven-3.8.6
export PATH=$PATH:${MVN}/bin

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{username}/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{username}/Library/Python/3.9/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"

export PATH="$PATH/usr/local/Homebrew/bin"
export PATH=“$PATH/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin”
```

With both mysql and brew line -> can't use both brew and mysql

If I remove mysql line -> can use brew but not mysql

If I remove both mysql and brew line -> can use brew but not mysql

---

ls /usr/local/opt with grep 'mysql' then

```bash
$> ls -al /usr/local/opt | grep mysql
lrwxr-xr-x   1 {username}  admin    24 10 12 11:05 mysql -> ../Cellar/mysql/8.0.30_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 {username}  admin    26 10 15 15:01 mysql@5.7 -> ../Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.39
lrwxr-xr-x   1 {username}  admin    24 10 12 11:05 mysql@8.0 -> ../Cellar/mysql/8.0.30_1
```

---

And I also checked [mysql command is not found after installing using homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262808/mysql-command-is-not-found-after-installing-using-homebrew).

but I cant figure out the cause

please help

Comment: Tip: You can use `$HOME` like some of your other definitions do. It keeps your path a lot less cluttered in files like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding elements to path, *do not forget* to put in the `:` separator. What you've done is just smashed this on the end, effectively fusing it to whatever unfortunate entry was last in the list.

Instead:

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin"
```

Also there's "smart quotes" in your code, which could be an issue. Those are not interpreted as quotes, but as part of the path.

When editing files like this, be sure to use a *code editor* and not a word processor. Word processors will substitute the quotes to make things look nice, but this will confuse the shell.

Comment: What a shameful mistake... Thank you.

Comment: @timothyjeong Happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the mysql path is incorrect. The correct path should be:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin"
```